# How to call a MVC web API action using Http client

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, http-request

My Http client code is:-

```
function GetWebApiClient() {
     var client = new HttpClient();
     client.BaseAddress = new Uri(http://localhost:68751);
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
     return client;
}

function sendRequest() {
     using (var client = GetWebApiClient())
     {
          HttpResponseMessage x = await client.GetAsync("api/XYZ/" + somevalue+ "/");
     }
}
```

controller code:-

```
public class XYZ : ApiController
{
     [System.Web.Mvc.AllowAnonymous]
     public string ABC(string id)
     {
           //need to call this function from client
           return "";
     }
}
```

each time when I am sending request it is returning with 400 Bad request.

Comment: shouldn't there be double quotes around your url in the new URI(... line? Could it be as simple as your controller method is called ABC, but you are calling for api/XYZ?

Comment: Try adding `FromUri` attribute for the `id` parameter. Refer this link as well http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

Answer (score 0):

Your method name needs to have the "Get" keyword or HttpGet attribute or it doesn't know which method to execute based on your Http Method.

```
public class XYZ : ApiController
{
     [System.Web.Mvc.AllowAnonymous]
     public string GetABC(string id)
     {
         //need to call this function from client
         return "";
     }
}
```

OR

```
public class XYZ : ApiController
{
     [System.Web.Mvc.AllowAnonymous]
     [HttpGet]
     public string ABC(string id)
     {
         //need to call this function from client
         return "";
     }
}
```

See here for more details: [WebApi Routing Documentation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api)

Comment: Thanks.I was using the authentication from MVC in the apiController function that's why it was not working.I changed it to HTTP and then it worked for me.